# Connect two Android devices using bluetooth programmatically

Tags: android

I am doing a bluetooth project in which i want to connect two devices using blutooth programaticaly.

I am following the guidelines and codes of tf developer.android.com.Can any one help me to resolve this issue?Here is the code i have tried.

Can anyone also tell me the from where the constructor receives the devices object?

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

<!-- can anyone tell me from where device object comes here   --!>
        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
            // because mmSocket is final
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) { }
                return;
            }

            // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
            manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
        }

        /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }


Thanks inadvance
```

Comment: Have you done your research yet?  Check out [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html](Android Blutooth)

Comment: Do your homework
Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

I am not sure why people are up voting this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some of my code that accomplishes the task.

```
    /**
     * Searches the list of paired devices for the device. Returns
     * if found, throws Exception otherwise.
     * 
     * @param sTargetDeviceName
     * @return BluetoothDevice 
     */
    private BluetoothDevice findDevice(String sTargetDeviceName) 
    throws Exception {

            BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = adapter.getBondedDevices();

            for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {

                    String sDeviceName = device.getName().trim();

                    if (sDeviceName.startsWith(sTargetDeviceName)) {
                            return device;
                    }
            }

            throw new Exception("Device " + sTargetDeviceName + " not found");
    }
```

To use the above code, the device must already be paired.

Please see the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

specifically the "Finding Devices" section.